Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $event ]] in class App\Livewire\Modal
I have a livewire component that is a modal:
class Modal extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['openModal', 'closeModal'];

    public $liveWireComponent = null;
    public $liveWireParams = [];

    public function openModal($event)
    {
        $this->liveWireComponent = $event['liveWireComponent'];
        $this->liveWireParams = json_decode($event['liveWireParams'], true);
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->liveWireComponent = null;
        $this->liveWireParams = [];
    }
}

I reference it in the template as this:
            <x-modal.button liveWireComponent="declaration-internal-notes-modal"
                            :liveWireParams="['declarationId' => $declaration->id]" class="button--light">
                Internal Notes
                @if ($declaration->hasInternalNotes())
                    <span class="unread"></span>
                @endif
            </x-modal.button>

Because I am using Livewire 3 I have an Alpine component in the alpine.js file as follows:
Alpine.data('modal', () => ({
    open: false,
    openModal(event) {
        this.open = true;
        this.$dispatch('openModal', event.detail);
    },
    closeModal() {
        this.open = false;
        this.$dispatch('closeModal');
    },
}));

When I click on the button to open the modal, it errors with 'Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $event ]] in class App\Livewire\Modal'. I have recently upgraded the project I'm on from Livewire 2 to Livewire 3, so I have a feeling it maybe related to this error, but otherwise I'm not sure what is going on with it.
